# Update Cursor: Unable to populate specific field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, loop, runtimeerror

I am attempting to create a loop to recognize the entry/exit point of a pipe to/from a structure by associating it with a North, South, East, or West direction and then populate the corresponding depth.  I presently cannot get the update cursor to work and receiving the error:

***Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 144, in 
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'updateRow'***

Code is listed below:  Image of Tables below that.

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
```

## Functions

```
def DepthSelection(inputDepth ,  depthDirection):
#From_fieldsStr_DEPTH = ["DEPTH" , "DEPTH_DIRECTION" , "DEPTH_2" , "DEPTH_2_DIRECTION" ,"DEPTH_3" , "DEPTH_3_DIRECTION" ,"DEPTH_4" , "DEPTH_4_DIRECTION"]
#DEPTH DIRECTION: Assocated Direction of Pipe With Specific Depth  
if depthDirection == "NORTH":
    associatedDepth = inputDepth  
    #print "associatedDepth ==" , associatedDepth ,"  depthDirection == NORTH"
elif depthDirection == "SOUTH":
    associatedDepth = inputDepth  
    #print "associatedDepth ==" , associatedDepth ,"  depthDirection == SOUTH"
elif depthDirection == "EAST":
    associatedDepth = inputDepth  
    #print "associatedDepth ==" , associatedDepth ,"  depthDirection == EAST"
elif depthDirection == "WEST":
    associatedDepth = inputDepth  
    #print "associatedDepth ==" , associatedDepth ,"  depthDirection == WEST"

return associatedDepth, depthDirection
```

## Environment

```
workspaceTEST = r"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\TESTSTRM_SWR.gdb"
ENV.workspace = workspaceTEST
```

## Variables

```
str15096 = workspaceTEST + "\STRUCTURES_15096"

pipes15096 = workspaceTEST + "\PIPES_15096"

From_fieldsStr_DEPTH = ["ID"  , "DEPTH" , "DEPTH_DIRECTION" , "DEPTH_2" , "DEPTH_2_DIRECTION" ,"DEPTH_3" , "DEPTH_3_DIRECTION" ,"DEPTH_4" , "DEPTH_4_DIRECTION"]

From_fieldsPipes_DEPTH = ["FROM_POINT"  , "FROM_DEPTH" , "FROM_DEPTH_DIRECTION"]
```

print "INITIAL PRINT TEST UPDATE: FROM_POINT in PIPES_15096"

## DEPTH

```
depthSearchCursor = ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(str15096, From_fieldsStr_DEPTH)
depthDict = {fromDepthRow[0]:(fromDepthRow[1:]) for fromDepthRow in depthSearchCursor}
depthFromDict = depthDict

with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(pipes15096, From_fieldsPipes_DEPTH) as fromUpdateCursor_4Depth:
    for updateFromRow in fromUpdateCursor_4Depth:
        depthKeyMaster = updateFromRow[0]
        print "DEPTH KEY MASTER = " , depthKeyMaster
        if depthKeyMaster in depthFromDict:
            print "DEPTH DESCRIPTION FROM DICTIONARY" , depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster]
            depthDirection1 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][1]
            depthDirection2 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][3]
            depthDirection3 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][5]
            depthDirection4 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][7]
            depth1 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][0]
            depth2 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][2]
            depth3 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][4]
            depth4 = depthFromDict[depthKeyMaster][6]

            #Function Utilization
            associatedDepth1 , depthDirection1 = DepthSelection(depth1 , depthDirection1)
            associatedDepth2 , depthDirection2 = DepthSelection(depth2 , depthDirection2)
            associatedDepth3 , depthDirection3 = DepthSelection(depth3 , depthDirection3)
            associatedDepth4 , depthDirection4 = DepthSelection(depth4 , depthDirection4)            


            print "TESTING THE DEPTH LOOP"                
            print "updateFromRow[2]     ", updateFromRow[2]
            print "associatedDepth2 " , associatedDepth2
            print "associatedDepth3 " , associatedDepth3
            print "associatedDepth4 " , associatedDepth4
            print "associatedDepth1 " , associatedDepth1
            if depthDirection2 == updateFromRow[2]:
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth[1].updateRow(associatedDepth2)
                print "UPDATE" , associatedDepth2
            elif depthDirection3 == updateFromRow[2]:
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth[1].updateRow(associatedDepth3)
                print "UPDATE" , associatedDepth3
            elif depthDirection4 == updateFromRow[2]:
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth[1].updateRow(associatedDepth4)
                print "UPDATE" , associatedDepth4
            else: 
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth[1].updateRow(associatedDepth1)
                print "UPDATE" , associatedDepth1
```

[image: Structure Table and Pipe Table]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have misunderstood how the `updateRow` method works.  It is a method of the cursor as a whole and takes a row object as its argument:

```
fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
```

You have to assign all of your update variables to the row object to write them to that row.  I am not sure how your update fields match up with the variables, but they would look something like:

```
updateFromRow[1] = associatedDepth2
```

Note:  You should assign all field value changes to the row first and only run `updateRow` once at the end of the for loop for that row.

Comment: You're correct sir.  I just read through a hand full of update cursor examples and realized that I never reclassified the value of the specific field location:

            if depthDirection2 == updateFromRow[2]:
                updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth2
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
                print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow
            if depthDirection3 == updateFromRow[2]:
                updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth3
                fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
                print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow

Answer (score 0):

```
        if depthDirection2 == updateFromRow[2]:
            updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth2
            fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
            print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow
        if depthDirection3 == updateFromRow[2]:
            updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth3
            fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
            print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow
        if depthDirection4 == updateFromRow[2]:
            updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth4
            fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
            print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow
        if depthDirection4 == updateFromRow[2]:  
            updateFromRow[1]= associatedDepth2
            fromUpdateCursor_4Depth.updateRow(updateFromRow)
            print "UPDATE" , updateFromRow
            print "update_DEPTH_Row1:  ", updateFromRow
```